# Protein Supplements and Gout

Tags: supplements

I have been using Protein Supplements for a year now
and try to eat high protein food everyday,
so I think I take high amount of protein daily

Now I  worried about Gout.
as far as I know it is caused by high protein intakes.

not sure if that is right and if so, shall i stop taking protein supplements?

Thanks

Comment: @JustSnilloc what other problems?!

Comment: Actually, I can’t seem to find any sources that look at extremely high protein consumption’s negative effects. There was one, but apparently they didn’t go high enough. So I suppose I’ll retract my former statement since it isn’t scientific, but just keep in mind that you can have too much of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High protein intake is not associated with an increased risk of gout.[[1]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15014182) People who are physically active are also less likely than the general population to develop gout.[[2]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18469274)

If you're not an alcoholic and you're not obese, you really have no reason to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Take high levels of proteins can conduce to unbalance your acid-base.

It can cause exhaustion, high blood pressure, etc.. To avoid that be sure to eat a lot of vegetables, water with lemons...

More than 1.5g/2g per kg (ex: 50 kg = 75-100g of proteins each day) is considered as useless by mosts of lifters. You will have no benefit after this point.